# x:DataType can't be resolved

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have this declaration in the XAML of my UWP application:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="AccountItemTemplate"
                  x:DataType="viewModels:AccountViewModel"
```

And this using:

```
xmlns:viewModels="using:MoneyFox.Business.ViewModels"
```

(That is also the using resharper generates for me)

And my object has this namespace:

```
namespace MoneyFox.Business.ViewModels
```

But I always get the following error in the designer:

```
"The name "AccountViewMode"l does not exist in namespace "using:MoneyFox.Business.ViewModels"
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Clean and rebuild?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I found out, that it works when I remove the refernece to the business project and readd it. But that only works until I restart VS =(